# How can I calculate the probability that two players different abilities will win a PARS squash game against each other? (Python)

Tags: python

I've created a function winProbability(ra, rb, n) and I want to simulate n games in order to estimate the probability that a player with the ability ra will win a game against a player with ability rb

I'll show the code I've done so far. If this seems like a easy issue it's because I am new to coding.

import random #import random allows for the use of randomly generated numbers

def game(ra, rb): #this function game sets out the way the game runs
p_a_point = ra/(ra+rb) #this line of code determines the probability that
#player a wins any given point

```
a_points = 0 #the amount of points player a has is defaulted to 0
b_points = 0 #the amount of points player b has is defaulted to 0

score_to_win = 11 #the winning score is defaulted to 11

while (a_points < score_to_win and b_points < score_to_win) or  abs (a_points - b_points) < 2: #while player a's points and player b's points are less than the winning score:
    p_b_point = random.random()#the probability b wins a point is set the a random value between 0 and 1
    if p_b_point < p_a_point: #is the probability b wins a point is less than the probability a wins a point:
        a_points = a_points + 1 #a wins 1 point
    else: #if player a doesn't win a point:
        b_points = b_points + 1 #b wins a point
return(a_points, b_points)#both players points are returned
```

print(game(70,30))#the function is called with two integer values as parameters

def winProbability(ra, rb, n):

To be honest from here I am unsure on how to go about this. I was thinking of doing a for loop so for example:
for n in game (ra, rb):

but I am unsure if I can use a previous function in this loop call. I'm also confused on how to calculate probabilities in code

The general aim is to call the function with two probabilities for example 70 and  30 and give a decimal answer for the probability player ra will win.

To previous commenters, I apologise for being vague before. I've never posted on here before.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far, any code we can look at.   Also, how would you convert the ratings into individual probabilities of winning points when serving and when receiving based on eachplayer's rating ?

Comment: I took his question to be one more about mathematics and ratios than about python. It is is an interesting ratio question, and not everyone has a firm grip on ratios. So even though I was tempted to reject it out of hand because it didn't ask a specific coding question, that didn't seem very welcoming of a new coder. You are correct, of course, Alain, that posters should share their efforts and ask about specific coding issues encountered, not general 'help me with my homework' goals.

Comment: If `ra` and `rb` add up to 1, then this seems like a straightforward calculation.

Comment: Yes, that is the key. ra + rb must add up to one to get the ratio we need. But it isn't so obvious that this is what is needed when you are matching up any two players from multiple players with skill levels such as 32, 98, 75, and 21.

Comment: @user10637953 If this is purely a math question and not a python/programming one, then there's a separate Stack Exchange site for that. If this is about the math + how to write the code for it in Python (tagged with Python), then OP should share current efforts and where specifically they are stuck, otherwise it's too broad IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
from random import randint, seed

seed()

rounds = input(" How many rounds will be played in the match? ")

print("\n Please enter skill levels as integers from 0 to 99.\n")
a = input(" What is the skill level of player 1? ")
b = input(" What is the skill level of player 2? ")


# Catch empty inputs
if not rounds: rounds = 10
if not a: a = 0
if not b: b = 0

# Python inputs are always strings. Convert them to integers.
rounds = int(rounds)
a = int(a)
b = int(b)

# If both skill levels are 0, set them to 1.
# (This will avoid a possible division by zero error.)
if a+b == 0: a = b = 1

# Catch and correct numbers that are too high.
if a > 99: a = 99
if b > 99: b = 99

# Convert integer skill levels to values between 0.0 and 0.99
a = a/100
b = b/100

print()
print(" Chance player 1 will win: "+str(int(100*a/(a+b)))+" percent.")
print(" Chance Player 2 will Win: "+str(int(100*b/(a+b)))+" percent.")
print()

for x in range(rounds):
    roll = randint(0,999)/1000
    print("roll =",roll, end =": ")
    if roll <= a/(a+b):  # <-- Compare roll to ratio of player skill levels.
        print("Round "+str(x+1)+" Winner: Player 1")
    else:
        print("Round "+str(x+1)+" Winner: Player 2")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my answer

```
import random

def winProbability(ra, rb, n):

    winCount = 0 #used to count how many times 'a' won
    probabilityRange = ra + rb

    for i in range(n):
        # pick a number between 0 and probabiilityRange
        number = random.randint(0, probabilityRange)

        # if number is < ra then 'a' won if number is > ra then 'b' won if number == ra then results in a draw
        if number < ra:
            winCount += 1
            print ('win')

        if number > ra:
            print('loss')

        if number == ra:
            print ('draw') # draw doesn't count as win

    return winCount*(100/n)

print (winProbability(10000,1,100000))
```

This prints the results of each game played, and returns the possibility that 'a' will win in percentile form.